# Update(link) database and DataGrid

Tags: vb.net

I want to have current information in my DataGrid as soon as I Save and Change my database. I want to edit the actual database and have the updated code in my DataGridView. Any advice would be great thanks.

So I update information in my database and save then close.

Then open my vb.net application Run it and the new data has been uploaded.

Comment: Is this winforms?  Is your `DataGridView` data-bound?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions, is there some kind of 
DataSet.Update i can do?

Comment: Look into using CSLA.NET.  Ideally your datagridview will be bound to a binding source which in turn is bound to a list object with each row being a child object.  All you'd need to do to refresh your gridview is call the list object's fetch method to draw everything back down from the database.

Comment: I actually got it to send information back and forth. I edited the relationships in Access and each time i save in Access I compact and repair. I also was able to publish that copy and get to the database still that i included in the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I Found Out how to keep data up to date.

1st you need to Make sure the Query's or Tables used in the VB project have the relationships set.  Open your Database----> Click Database Tools----> Click Relationships----> Show all tables and query's in the display view----> Drag Matching Fields From Query's to The Table.

2nd After you save all your Edits Click File on the Menu Strip----> Click Info on Left Menu Bar----> Click Compact and Repair